# Drawing empty dummy columns on loop

Tags: php, css, html, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Consider the following data array is assigned to "$my_array". I've included a screenshot of the expected output based on the data given on the bottom of this post.

Note: For some reason I can't modify the insertion of data on the database that's why I need to draw empty columns base on this structure.

```
Array
(
[1] => Array //This is row #1
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => column 2 text
                [1] => column2 //column identifier
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => column 3 text
                [1] => column3 //column identifier
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => column 4 text
                [1] => column4 //column identifier
            )
    )

[2] => Array //This is row #2
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => column 1 text
                [1] => column1 //column identifier
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => column 4 text
                [1] => column4 //column identifier
            )

    )
)
```

Here's a thing:

I want to draw 4 column on each row no matter if the row returns 1, 2 or 3 column data. I'm able to add an identifier on which column should be column will be drawn.

What I've so far is something like this:
Note: I really don't know how to determine if some of the columns is not on the row data and add empty space so this is what I've so far:

```
foreach($my_array as $row) {
    echo '<div class="row">'; //draw the rows

    //I used for loop instead of foreach to create four columns
    for($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
        //draw the column here

        //write column text data $row[$x][0]
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on that you always want to have 4 columns, you can do it the following way:

```
$columns = ['column1','column2','column3','column4'];        // create list to check for identifier
foreach($my_array as $row) {
  echo '<div class="row">';
  $drawColumns = [0,0,0,0];                                  // if 0, col empty, if 1 data exist
  $columnIndex = [0,0,0,0];
  foreach($row as $index => $column) {                                  // loop over row to fill $drawColumns 
    $columnPosition = array_search($column[1],$columns);     // array_search gives index of the found entry
    $drawColumns[$columnPosition] = 1;                       // mark column as not empty
    $columnIndex[$columnPosition] = $index;         // store the original index of the column in the row
  }
  for($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {                                // just loop over drawColumns 
    if ($drawColumns[$x] == 1) {                             // draw data if exists
      echo '<div class="col">'.$row[$columnIndex[$x]][0].'</div>';
    } else {                                                 // else draw empty column
      echo '<div class="col">empty column</div>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This works but I didn't know why some of the columns doesn't write a value. But the positioning works great. And also I added a <div class="row"> on top of $drawColumns = [0,0,0,0]; 

Will continue to check with this code why there's a blank data. It's weird. There is always blank data. I tested it on 10 different data arrays.

Comment: I just updated my answer. The problem was the index I used to get the value from $row. Because $x was not equal to the index the column originally was in $my_array.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($row as $r){
    $colid[] = $r['1'];
}
for($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
    if(in_array($row[$x]['1'],$colid)){
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">'.$row[$x]['1'].'</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">Empty Cell</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Rows and end of rows div will be as usual.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($my_array as $row) {
    echo '<div class="row">';

    for($x = 1; $x <= 4; $x++) {
      $colval = '-'; // default value to output for empty column;
                     // you can also use an empty string or other placeholder
      foreach($row as $val) {
        if( $val[1] == 'column'.$x ) {
          $colval = $val[0]; // take this value, if entry with columnX exists
          break;
        }
      }
      echo '<div class="col">', $colval, '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: The code didn't work. It run and give some good value but it didn't tally to the data array.

Comment: _“but it didn't tally to the data array”_ - what do you mean by that? I tested it with the sample data you had given, and it worked fine.